# Pigeon holes principle

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Let $P$ be a group that it's elements are 257 sentences in which only atomic sentences from $A,B,C$ exist (i.e. $A \iff B,\space\space A \wedge B \wedge C, \space\space...$) Show that there exists two different $p_1, p_2 \in P$ so that the sentence $p_1 \iff p_2$ is a tautology.

Pigeons are the $257$ sentences but I can't think of a way to prove the asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Notice that $257=2^8+1$, so you might guess that there will be $2^8$ pigeonholes. You have three atomic sentences. They can have $2^3=8$ different combinations of truth values. How many different truth **tables** can you build from these $8$ combinations of truth values? Now notice that if $p_1\iff p_2$ is a tautology, then $p_1$ and $p_2$ have the same truth table. (Why?)

Comment: I don't really know how to answer the question *How many different truth tables can you build from these $8$ combinations of truth values?* We have $257$ so could it possibly be $257 \times 84$? It doesn't feel like it.

Comment: @Georgey: Each truth table with three atomic sentences will have $8$ lines. (Why?) Say that it’s the truth table for some proposition $p$; on each of those $8$ lines $p$ will have a truth value, either T or F. How many different ways are there to assign those $8$ truth values?

Comment: Each truth table with $n$ atomic sentences will have $2^n$ lines, because for each variable ($n$ variables) it can get truth or false values ($2$ values). So the answer for your second question if $2^8$? Because each truth value can get true or false value?

Comment: @Georgey: That’s right. There are $2^8$ possible truth tables for a proposition $p$ containing at most the three atomic sentences $A,B$, and $C$. And $P$ contains $257$ propositions, so ... ?

Comment: so according to *Pigeonhole principle* there are at least $\left \lceil \frac{257}{2^8} \right \rceil = \left \lceil \frac{257}{256} \right \rceil = 2$ sentences that have an identical truth table which means they're tautology. What I don't understand is why shouldn't I divide it to different cases. 1. where there are only $A$ and $B$ and 2. where there are $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Comment: @Georgey: You don’t need the cases, because a proposition that uses only $A$, let’s say, still has an $8$-line truth table involving $B$ and $C$ as well. It’s just that the lines for TTT, TTF, TFT, and TFF (where the first symbol is for $A$, the second for $B$, and the third for $C$) will all give the proposition the same truth value, since only the truth value of $A$ actually matters.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the truth tables.  How many different possible truth tables are there for sentences with three variables?  What can you say about sentences that have the same truth table?

Answer (score 0):

1. How many different truth-functions are expressible using just three propositional variables? (Hint: how many lines are there in a truth-table in three variables? how many truth-possibilities are there for each line? So how many different truth-functions in three variables in total?)
2. If there are $x$ different truth-functions in three variables and $y$ different wffs built up from three variables, and $x < y$, how might the pigeon hole principle be applied?